# Problem with enumerate environment in answers package

Tags: packages, enumerate, answers

Here is a mwe showcasing the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage{answers}
        \Newassociation{sol}{enumerate}{ans}
        \newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
            \begin{document}
        \Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]
        \section{Problems}
        \begin{ex}
        First exercise
        \begin{sol}
         \item First solution.
         \begin{enumerate}
            \item 
            \item
         \end{enumerate}
        \end{sol}
        \end{ex}
        \begin{ex}
        Second exercise
        \begin{sol}
        \item Second solution.
        \end{sol}
        \end{ex}
        \Closesolutionfile{ans}
        \section{Solutions}
        \input{ans1}
        \end{document}
```

This gives an error message. Here is the answers file generated.

```
\begin{enumerate}\enumerateparams 
 \item First solution.
 \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \item
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}\enumerateparams 
Second solution.
\end{enumerate}
```

As one can see, there is an extra \enumerateparams.
I don't know how to get rid of this. I tried the hack

```
\newcommand{\enumerateparams}{\relax}
```

This doesn't solve the issue either. The following are the details about my TeX Live distribution.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.9.23)  4 MAR 2020 10:53
```

This is the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \begin{enumerate}\enumerateparams

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the line

```
\newcommand{\enumerateparams}{}
```

and it worked!:)